# Tag Cleanup: Digital-Recording, Recording and Video-Recording

Tags: discussion

Now that the site is focusing on video production, these three tags are effectively redundant.  We may want a "film-recording" tag on the exceptionally rare case that someone is dealing with an old film setup, but the vast majority of on topic recordings will now simply be digital video recordings.

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-recording

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-recording

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording

Answer (score 2):

I propose that the new tag should simply be video-recording.